# Many icon buttons cause site to slow down dramatically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I implemented a star rating control, which consists of five material icon buttons:

```html
<div class="row-nowrap">
  <button
    mat-icon-button
    class="starButton"
    disableRipple="true"
    *ngFor="let star of stars; let i = index"
    (click)="onClick(i + 1)"
    [ngClass]="customClass"
    [color]="color">
    <mat-icon>
      {{star}}
    </mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

Here's the backend code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-star-rating',
  templateUrl: './star-rating.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./star-rating.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class StarRatingComponent implements OnInit {
  private _rating: number;
  @Input() public set rating(rating: number){
    if (this._rating === rating) return;
    this._rating = rating;
    this.updateStarArray(this._rating);
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  };
  public get rating(): number { return this._rating; }
  @Input() public starCount: number = 5;
  @Input() public isReadOnly: boolean = false;
  @Input() public color: string = 'warn';
  @Input() public size: string = '';
  public customClass: string;
  @Output() public ratingUpdated = new EventEmitter();
  public stars: string[];

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customClass = {
      'medium': 'medium-icon-button',
      'small': 'small-icon-button',
      'tiny': 'tiny-icon-button',
      'dwarf': 'dwarf-icon-button'
    }[this.size] || '';
  }

  onClick(rating: number) {
    if (this.isReadOnly)
      return;

    if (this.rating === rating)
      this.rating--;
    else
      this.rating = rating;

    this.ratingUpdated.emit(this.rating);
  }

  updateStarArray(rating: number) {
    const stars: string[] = [];
    const ratingFull = Math.floor(rating);
    const ratingRemainer = Math.round((rating % 1) * 10);

    for (let i = 1; i <= this.starCount; i++) {
      let star: string;

      if (ratingFull >= i) {
        star = 'star';
      } else if (ratingFull + 1 === i) {
        if (ratingRemainer < 3)
          star = 'star_border';
        else if (ratingRemainer > 7)
          star = 'star';
        else
          star = 'star_half';
      } else {
        star = 'star_border';
      }

      stars.push(star);
    }

    this.stars = stars;
  }
}
```

The component itself works perfectly. At least as long as it's not used too often on one page. However I hava a table with about 200 entries. The table has [expandable rows](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples), which show 15 of these star ratings. So altogether the table contains 3,000 star rating controls or 15,000 icon buttons. Pagination is unfortunately not an option due to the nature of the table.

This causes the site to be loaded in 8 seconds. Each action like sorting the table takes 1-2 seconds.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled over [this](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13431) github issue, which indirectly solves my problem. Using an `ngIf` instead of an animation leads to the details obviously not loaded/rendered upfront:

```html
<div class="detail" *ngIf="u.isExpanded"> 
...
</div>
```

Now I don't have an animation when a row is expanded, but I can live with that. Everything is running extremely fast again. Problem solved.